# Which is correct and why? "How can I not...?" or "How can't I...?"

Tags: word-order, questions, negation, contractions

1. How can I not know this?
2. How can't I know this?

Which one of the two sentences is correct? Or maybe they are both correct, but different in meaning.

Comment: (2) is not idiomatic English. (1) is possible, but something like "How does it come about that I don't know this?" would be more natural.

Comment: They are both grammatically correct, but I believe you will hear the first one more often..